# Express "PUT all variables" in a data step to export SAS data

Tags: text, export, sas, datastep

Goal: export an entire SAS dataset to a tab-delimited text file using a data step.

Problem: In every example that I can find, such as [this one](http://www.ciser.cornell.edu/FAQ/SAS/write_delimited_file.shtml), one must specify every variable in the data step following the PUT statement.  **Isn't there a simple method to just ask for "all" of the variables?**

I have already tried using `PUT _ALL_`, but that includes the variable names in every row of the output, instead of just outputtin the values.

Comment: 1) Why not PROC EXPORT with DBMS=TAB? 2) Is order of variables important?

Comment: @vasja, I happen to want also to specify the ENCODING option in my datastep, and I'm not aware of such a capability in PROC EXPORT.

Comment: Zkurtz... include everything you are trying to do... I suspect a data step may not be able to do what you want.

Comment: You may be able to do so in the `filename`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it in a data step, AND don't want to specify things, but really don't want `PROC EXPORT` making decisions for you, AND have data that's reasonably easily specified (nothing fancy like dates you want in a special format), you can do this.

```
proc sql;
select name into :namelist separated by ' ' 
from dictionary.columns
where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS'; *these are the libname/dataset name you want;
quit; 

filename blah temp;
data _null_;
set sashelp.class;
file blah dlm='09'x;
put &namelist.;
run;
```

You can customize it some depending on your needs by modifying the sql query (such as if you have a set of variables with `_date` perhaps you could modify it to add `name||' :date9.'` in the sql query for those.

Note that the libname/memname/name fields in dictionary.columns are typically upper case.  They are not *always* upper case, I don't think, but they almost always are.  (Some RDBMSs for example can override this, I believe).

Comment: working through this -- just noticed that evidently it is essential that 'SASHELP' and 'CLASS' are uppercase.

Comment: curious about the function of the 'filename blah temp' line

Comment: I'm just lazy.  That's me writing out to a temporary file I won't have to delete later.  :)  `temp` as a keyword on a filename statement means it's written to your work directory.

Comment: Correct - the memname / name dictionary fields are not always uppercase, even for SAS datasets.  Something to keep in mind..

Answer (score 1):

@Joe's brilliant and quick as always.

For reference, many options, including `ENCODING` are possible with `FILENAME`. Those should be usable anywhere file path is allowed.

```
FILENAME myfile "E:\test.csv" encoding=wlatin2;

PROC EXPORT
DATA=sashelp.class
OUTFILE=myfile
DBMS=TAB REPLACE;
run;
```

Comment: I tested this, and it looks like it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In a datastep I find when I just want to get a list of the values using

```
put (_all_)(=/);
```

For example:

```
data a; 
  ref=today();
  monday = intnx('week1.2',ref,-1,'Begin');
  sunday = intnx('week1.2',ref,-1,'End');
  week_end_Friday=intnx('day',(intnx('weeks',ref,0,'end')),-1);
  week_end_cur=intnx('weeks',ref,0,'end');
  format _all_ weekdate.; 
  put (_all_)(=/);
run;
```

/* or to look at a few records or modify for specific conditions */

```
data test;
  set test;
  if _n_ < 5 then do;
    PUT (_ALL_)(=/);  
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both a variable list and format list to use the `_ALL_` keyword in the `PUT` statement and not have it generate the names.  The format list does not need to contain any actual formats but it cannot be empty.  So this code will create a CSV file, without column headers.

```
data _null_;
  file 'want.csv' dsd ;
  set have ;
  put (_all_) (+0) ;
run;
```

If you do want column headers there are a couple of methods you could use.  Here is one that uses `PROC TRANSPOSE` to generate a dataset with the variable names. This can be used to write the header row and then the above code can be used with just the addition of the `MOD` keyword to the `FILE` statement to append the data records.

```
proc transpose data=have(obs=0) out=names ;
  var _all_;
run;
data _null_;
  file 'want.csv' dsd ;
  set names end=eof;
  put _name_ @ ;
  if eof then put;
run;
```